# Using apply_filters inside an add_action function not applying filter changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin, and I'm using `add_action` to hook into `auth_cookie_valid` to alter how login cookies are handled.

I want to create a filter inside the hook to allow users to control the logic a little.

I have this inside my `auth_cookie_valid` hook which has the default value `false`, then applies the filter:

```
$allowDuplicateSessions = false;
$allowDuplicateSessions = apply_filters('persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions', $allowDuplicateSessions);
```

and in `functions.php` I have this to make it true:

```
function handle_persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions($allowDuplicateSessions) {
    $allowDuplicateSessions = true;
    return $allowDuplicateSessions;
}
add_filter('persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions', 'handle_persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions');
```

However, `$allowDuplicateSessions` always returns false.

I'm wondering if the filter in `functions.php` is running too late for the `auth_cookie_valid` hook? I haven't spotted anything in the documentation though.

I think this because I moved my `apply_filters` code to the `wp_footer` action hook and it returned `true`. So I'm starting to think that the issue is with `auth_cookie_valid`?

Function as requested below (I've removed a lot of irrelevant lines as it's quite a big function:

```
// update auth cookie with new login time, expiry time & IP address
function persistent_login_update_auth_cookie($cookieElements, $user) {

    if( $user ) :
        $persistent_login_roles = get_option( 'persistent_login_options_user_access' );

        if( $persistent_login_roles ) :
            if( array_intersect($user->roles, $persistent_login_roles) ) : 

                // update the cookie expiration time
                $options = get_option('persistent_login_options_premium');
                if( $options ) :
                    $expiration = $options['cookieTime'];                           
                else :
                    $expiration = strtotime('1 year', 0); // 1 year default
                endif;

                // update the IP address and login time of the cookie
                $sessionToken = $cookieElements['token'];

                if ( function_exists( 'hash' ) ) :
                    $verifier = hash('sha256', $sessionToken);
                else :
                    $verifier = sha1( $sessionToken);
                endif;                      

                $sessions = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'session_tokens', true);
                $sessions[$verifier]['login'] = time();
                $sessions[$verifier]['expiration'] = time()+$expiration;
                $sessions[$verifier]['ip'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

                // update the token with new data
                $wp_session_token = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user->ID);
                $wp_session_token->update( $sessionToken, $sessions[$verifier]);

                // apply filter for allowing duplicate sessions
                $allowDuplicateSessions = false;
                $allowDuplicateSessions = apply_filters('persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions', $allowDuplicateSessions); 

                // remove any exact matches to this session
                foreach ($sessions as $key => $session) :
                    if( $key !== $verifier ) : 

                        if( is_bool($allowDuplicateSessions) ) :
                            if( $allowDuplicateSessions === false ) :

                                // if we're on the same user agent and same IP, we're probably on the same device
                                // delete the duplicate session
                                if( 
                                    ($session['ip'] === $sessions[$verifier]['ip']) &&
                                    ($session['ua'] === $sessions[$verifier]['ua'])
                                ) :
                                    $updateSession = new Persistent_Login_Manage_Sessions($user->ID);
                                    $updateSession->persistent_login_update_session($key);                                               
                                endif;

                            endif;
                        else :
                            return new WP_Error( 'broke', __( "Error, expected boolean value in persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions filter." ) );
                        endif; // end boolean check

                    endif; // if key is different to identifier 
                endforeach;

                // set users local cookie again - checks if they should be remembered
                $rememberUserCheck = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'persistent_login_remember_me', true);

                if( $rememberUserCheck === 'true' ) :

                    // if the user should be remembered, reset the cookie so the cookie time is reset
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, is_ssl(), $sessionToken);

                else : 

                    // if the users doen't want to be remembered, don't re-set the cookie

                endif; 

            endif; // end if roles match the user roles
        endif; // endif persistent login roles
     endif; // endif user
    }
    add_action('auth_cookie_valid', 'persistent_login_update_auth_cookie', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Can you add the `add_action('auth_cookie_valid')` part to the question too? To make sure that the add_action is done correctly. Or the complete function were the `apply_filters('persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions', $allowDuplicateSessions);` is located.

Comment: Hi, I've added the entire function (though it is quote big!)

Comment: Just to test: If you replace `apply_filters('persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions', $allowDuplicateSessions);` with `handle_persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions($allowDuplicateSessions)` inside the `persistent_login_update_auth_cookie ()`, does it return true or false?

Comment: Sorry this took so long. Interesting...it returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined function handle_persistent_login_allow_duplicate_sessions()` during login, but if I'm logged in and load up a page, it returns true.

Comment: it means that when you are trying to access that function inside the hook `auth_cookie_valid`, your function is not yet registered. That is the reason it is not being executed with `apply_filter`.  You can try to add the functionality inside the `auth_cookie_valid`. You can also find the sequence of how hooks are being executed here: http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/